# Can a hashtag '#' be used as a comment in assembly (NASM)?

Tags: assembly, x86, comments

I'm following [this assembly source code](https://github.com/redox-os/bootloader/blob/master/x86_64/startup-common.asm) for learning purposes and came across the following lines:

```
# load a disk extent into high memory
# eax - sector address
# ecx - sector count
# edi - destination
load_extent:
    ; loading kernel to 1MiB
    ; move part of kernel to startup_end via bootsector#load and then copy it up
    ; repeat until all of the kernel is loaded
    buffer_size_sectors equ 127
```

There are lines beginning with `#` which appear to be comments.

He then follows up with the label `load_extent:` and adds comments which start with `;`. Which is what I'm used to seeing.

Was this done intentionally so people don't carelessly copy his code? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can those who downvote please give a reason, or at least flag the question for specific reasons, so maybe I can ask better questions in future. Silent downvotes really don't help anyone.

Comment: So without specifying the exact version of assembler used in your case it is pointless to reason why `#` was used, it can be just a mistake on the author side, or it can be valid start-comment character in his assembler (I guess your lack of target CPU + assembler caused somebody to downvote).

Comment: @Ped7g - Ahhh that makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: @UndercoverCoder I could imagine someone downvoted you because you called `#` a *hashtag* which isn't the name of this character at all.  However, this is a bit silly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I went through whole [NASM documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc0.html), and there's no mention of hash being comment character, yet my own experiment with NASM v 2.11.08 shows the line starting with `#` is treated as comment line. So it looks like unofficial feature of NASM. Only `;` character is mentioned in documentation.

Curiously enough, the line:

```
xx: # inc ebx
```

Where hash is used after label will fail with *"error: parser: instruction expected"*.

Also from the NASM history change-list: *"#, @, ~ and c{?} are now valid characters in labels."* since v0.91 from 1996, so `xx#yy:` defines symbolic label `xx#yy`.

This makes it somewhat compatible with sh scripts, and can be probably abused somewhat more when creating mixed header file for both C and NASM, where NASM will ignore then C preprocessor directives, so this may be useful.

But I would advice against using this, at least until it is officially admitted this is intentional feature of NASM, and not some bug of parser.

---

Some chit-chat from my early comments before answering this with full answer:

Assembly is not a single programming language, but general term for all the machine language mnemonics => has no rules.

Each CPU vendor has it's own instruction set(s) ("ISA"), and it needs particular assembler, and each assembler vendor tends to fill up the gaps missing in official docs (which are only describing instruction functionality, not bothering to define full valid syntax of programming language), so even on the same CPU you can have assemblers with slightly different dialects, one supporting # as comment, other not.

On x86 there're even assemblers with majorly different syntax: AT&T vs NASM, far beyond additional comment-start character, actually reversing order of operands for instructions, and using different mnemonics for some instructions (`movzbl` vs `movzx` for example), etc...

For other example: in popular (at universities courses) MIPS simulators "MARS" and "SPIM" the `#` is the only comment character instead of `;`, but that is well documented in their official docs (and not relevant to x86).

Answer (score 2):

As of NASM 2.16, placing a `#` at the start of a line is a [documented feature](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.01/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.13.1) where the `#` acts as an alias for the `%line` directive:

> **4.13.1 `%line` Directive**
>
> ...
>
> For compatibility with the output from some other preprocessors, including many C preprocessors, a `#` character followed by whitespace at the very beginning of a line is also treated as a `%line` directive, except that double quotes surrounding the filename are treated like NASM backquotes, with `\`–escaped sequences decoded.

A consequence of this is that NASM fails to assemble the code in question at the preprocessing stage, since that naturally is not valid syntax for the `%line` directive.

However, if you add the [`--no-line` option](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.01/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.33) (introduced in version 2.14.01) when running NASM, all `%line` directives are ignored by the preprocessor, effectively making `%line`, and in turn `#`, a marker for the start of a comment. So if you've got some old code written for a previous version of NASM that uses `#` for comments and doesn't contain any other `%line` directives (which is most probably the case) then appending `--no-line` to your NASM command is an easy fix for NASM 2.16+.

---

Weirdly enough though, I can't seem to find any mention of this change in [Appendix C](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.01/html/nasmdocc.html) of the manual. Maybe it just wasn't considered significant enough to warrant being noted here? I honestly doubt that, but I can't really think up a better reason.